# I want to a wordpress newsletter plugin

Tags: wordpress, newsletter, subscribe

I have a blog site. I want to setup a "subscribe" option.

Newsletter Specification.
1. A man who subscribe my site, he accept all new blog post shortly with this post link.
2. I want to mail subscriber at a time regularly. Such as 6.00am GMT.

Comment: I suggest moving this to wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Well if you searched on google you would have got this for sure as the first link:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/newsletter/

Comment: Is it require my condition please ?
My require are-
1. This newsletter send 6.00 GMT mail all subscriber.
2. Mail must be short of full blog post and with this blog post links

Comment: Well check it out no? If it doesn't work for you do some more searching, develop it yourself, or pay someone to do it for you. This is for asking technical questions not for asking people to analyse your requirements!